# How generate link for office 365 online for ALL items in a folder, in a quickly way

Tags: excel, excel-online

i try to explain my issue.

I created a folder in sharepoint then added some excel file (xls). 
Now i want to export the list of the link of all items, but NOT in that way 
https://mywebsite.sharepoint.com/Folder/File1.xls,
https://mywebsite.sharepoint.com/Folder/File2.xls...

I want the link for opening directly on line so i click on the item, get a link, wait some seconds and i have the url like this: https://mywebsite.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/nlitteam/ETNfR_9hXmBFvLVoaW_tdgIBugTU6eVVgJdf01nLEWzNKw?e=wHdpLo

and **that's i want**, but for **all** items (they are more than 200) i cannot do this operation for each one, otherwise i will become old.

I imagine there is a way to get all the links in that way for all items on the folder, but searching the web i cannot find any on that, also if I export in excel, i get the link in that way (https://mywebsite.sharepoint.com/Folder/File1.xls) but i don't want this!!

Please, help me

Comment: So do you want the urls to open up the Online version of Excel?

Comment: Are you just trying to get a URL that will open the document in Excel Online?  If so, just add `?web=1` to the end of the link with the filename - i.e. `https://mywebsite.sharepoint.com/Folder/File2.xls?web=1`.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple.
Since you are exporting to an excel, all you have to do is to create a new column which is a calculated one and it would combine the existing url & append "?Web=1" at the end

Example:

> Existing Url Column in Excel (assuming its Column H):
>   https://server/documents/file.xlsx
>
> New calculated column: H + "?Web=1" Final result would be:
>   https://server/documents/file.xlsx?Web=1

I just tested it and it works.